# Can be a function of continuous random variable be discrete?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

If $\xi$ is a continuous random variable, if there is any continuous function $g$ that $g(\xi)$ will be a discrete random variable?

Answer (score 0):

If you assume $g$ is continuous, $\xi$ is continuous, and the support of $\xi$ is an interval, then the only way for $g(\xi)$ to be discrete is if $g$ is constant on the support of $\xi$. In this case $g(\xi)$ is a constant random variable, which is indeed discrete.

If you don't assume the support of $g$ is an interval (for example if its density is $1/2$ on $(0,1)$ and $1/2$ on $(2,3)$ and $0$ elsewhere), then you can cook up a continuous function $g$ which is constant on each component of the support of $\xi$, but with different constants on each component. In this case $g(\xi)$ will take on as many values as the support of $\xi$ has components.

So for example you can have $g(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & x \in (-\infty,1) \\ x-1 & x \in [1,2) \\ 1 & x \in [2,\infty) \end{cases}$ with my $\xi$ from the previous paragraph, and then $g(\xi)$ is a Bernoulli(1/2) variable.